# Ansible filter for json object

Tags: ansible

I am trying to filter out the below information with json_query.

```
{"instance_info": {
        "addresses": "inner-net_NC_ENG_IT_DPL=192.168.190.9, 10.199.224.71",
        "config_drive": "",
        "flavor": "IaaS.Vcpu_2.ram_6 (5b6cd78e-8804-4371-82bb-6d5b6e0b51c1)",
        "image": "rhel7.2 (5a03b53e-0950-4f94-97c1-9177ac7b09ae)",
        "security_groups": "name='default'",
        "user_id": "36f6ff7d2b0a47b4ae37ff804842583f",
        "volumes_attached": "id='a6682f1e-d974-449d-a8f8-2610c05796f6'"
    }
}
```

I want to filter out and register flavor Id (5b6cd78e-8804-4371-82bb-6d5b6e0b51c1) to reuse in my role.
so far what I did.

```
- name: Getting the flavor_ID
  set_fact:
    flavor_id: "{{ (instance_info | to_json | from_json) | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "flavor"
```

---

so the out put is

```
"flavor": "IaaS.Vcpu_2.ram_6 (5b6cd78e-8804-4371-82bb-6d5b6e0b51c1)
```

but I only want out put as `5b6cd78e-8804-4371-82bb-6d5b6e0b51c1`

Comment: Hi...WC to SO! Kindly go through..https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. This will help you to understand how to create a better OP in SO!.

Comment: You need to extract the part you need from your value with e.g. [`regex_replace` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Variables:**

```
vars:
  flavor: "IaaS.Vcpu_2.ram_6 (5b6cd78e-8804-4371-82bb-6d5b6e0b51c1)"
```

**Tasks:**

```
- debug:
   msg: "{{flavor| regex_replace('^.* \\((.*)\\)','\\1')}}"
```

**Output:**

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "msg": "5b6cd78e-8804-4371-82bb-6d5b6e0b51c1"
>   }

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's working.  how can I grow my skill with this? any link?

Comment: please mark the answer as solution. Here are some examples which you can refer. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html